# How to Check whether a model is Rendered in the Scene in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

how to check whether an object is fully  rendered in the browser in THREE.js.

I have tried this in animate function

```
if(Scene.getObjectByName('object')!= undefined)
{
console.log("rendered");
}
```

but the rendered model show only after a few seconds on displaying the console message .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it can be done using the THREE.js loading manager

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

    console.log( item, loaded, total );


};
```